# Can a custom AngularJs directive be written inside a partial

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to AngularJs. Want to check if I can have a custom directive inside a partial file? If yes, then how many times the link function gets called when the partial is mapped to the `data-ng-view` on the main html file?

Updated the code in [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/prashdeep/s8f3r/). Please forgive me for the mistakes in the jsfiddle since I am new to using it. The code on jsfiddle is to get the essence of what I am trying to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

> Want to check if I can have a custom directive inside a partial file?

**Yes**

> If yes, then how many times the link function gets called when the partial is mapped to the data-ng-view on the main html file?

**Every time you navigate to the view the link function would get called. Whenever any view is loaded either through ng-view, ng-include the link function gets executed.**

Comment: If the partial is loaded into the ng-view then, does that mean, the link will be called twice. The same thing is happening with my code. The link is getting called when the partial containing the custom directive is loaded into the ng-view. If so, how can I make sure that the link gets called only once and not twice?

Comment: It should get called once only.

Comment: Its getting called twice. What do I need to do?

Comment: See if you have declared your controller `IndexCtrl` in html with ng-controller too, or check if your directive `glass-carousel` has been declared at multiple places.